# Fetch recent user media from instagram with php

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

How can I fetch recent photos from my own Instagram with php? I have been trying some classes in github, but couldn't get them work. Also they are quite old(2012,2013). Can anyone help me suggesting a working class/script? I just want to fetch 4 most recent photos and show them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this PHP wrapper. It is up todate and just works.

[cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API)

After you authenticate, you can use the following method (sample code is on github) to get the user's recent media.

`getUserFeed(<$limit>)`